# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Venue'

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, google-cloud-firestore, navigator

This is my problem. In a screen, I'm using a `Navigator.pushnamed()...` with arguments to send info to a screen with a detailed view. It works fine! This is the code:

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, VenueDetailScreen.id, arguments: snapshot.data[index]);`

In a `SearchDelegate`, I'm trying to do the same in `buildSuggestions`, but I'm having an error. This are the code and the error:

```
results.map<Widget>(
                (a) => Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(a.data);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, VenueDetailScreen.id, arguments: a.data);
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        a.data['nombre'].toString(),
                      ),
```

The error:
`type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Venue'`

I'll appreciate your help to understand what isn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.data` is a map you need to cast it to the model by doing something like `Venue.fromJson(a.data)`

```dart
results.map<Widget>(
                (a) => Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(a.data);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, VenueDetailScreen.id, arguments: Venue.fromJson(a.data));
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        a.data['nombre'].toString(),
                      ),
```